# XSLT 1.0 (xsltproc) - Output only the last duplicate node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How do I output just the last duplicate node using XSLT 1.0?
I use xsltproc processor.

Input.xml

```
<testng-results>
    <suite>
        <test>
            <class name="system.apps.CreateTerritory">
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="FAIL"  name="ABC"> </test-method>
            </class>
            <class name="system.apps.CreateAccount">
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="SKIP"  name="DEF"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="FAIL"  name="DEF"> </test-method>
            </class>
        </test>
    </suite>
</testng-results>
```

My Current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Suite>
            <xsl:for-each select="testng-results/suite/test/class">
                 <xsl:for-each select="test-method">
                     <xsl:if test="not(@is-config)">
                             <Test>
                                 <Method_Name>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                 </Method_Name>
                                 <Status>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                                 </Status>
                             </Test>
                     </xsl:if>
                 </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Suite>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: I can't change the way the nested match is done (for-each class and then for-each test-method as I need to be this way for other reasons)

Current Output.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Suite>
  <Test>
    <Method_Name>ABC</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
    <Status>SKIP</Status>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
</Suite>
```

Expected Output.xml (only the last node is outputted for every duplicate test-method):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Suite>
  <Test>
    <Method_Name>ABC</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
</Suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `xsltproc` (that is the `libxslt` processor), you can take advantage of the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function in order to utilize a shortened version of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="test-by-name" match="test-method[not(@is-config)]" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/testng-results">
    <xsl:variable name="tests" select="suite/test/class/test-method[not(@is-config)]" />
    <Suite>
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct($tests/@name)">
            <Test>
                <Method_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </Method_Name>
                <Status>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('test-by-name', .)[last()]/@status"/>
                </Status>
            </Test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Suite>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer, you can do it in pure XSLT 1.0 as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="test-by-name" match="test-method[not(@is-config)]" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/testng-results">
    <Suite>
        <xsl:for-each select="suite/test/class/test-method[not(@is-config)][count(. | key('test-by-name', @name)[last()]) = 1]">
            <Test>
                <Method_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </Method_Name>
                <Status>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                </Status>
            </Test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Suite>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note the use of the `[last()]` predicate instead of the usual `[1]`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting a small issue with this.
If there is a test method with the name 'DEF' in two different classes. It lists only the second one and omits the first one, even though the 'DEF' method is unique for its own parent class. The requirement was to check duplicates only within one class. Not across all classes. Would you kindly be able to edit your answer for that?

Comment: I am using your pure XSLT 1.0 solution, by the way.

Comment: You need to add a unique identifier of the parent class to the key.

Comment: I tried:
<xsl:key name="test-by-name" match="test-method[not(@is-config)]" use="../@name" />

with and without : <xsl:for-each select="suite/test/class/test-method[not(@is-config)][count(. | key('test-by-name', ../@name)[last()]) = 1]">

Not working as desired.

Comment: I wonder if I should create a separate question for this requirement.

Comment: Well, you did so I will not continue here.