# XSLT 1.0 (xsltproc) - Output only the last duplicate node WITHIN the upper/parent element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How do I output just the last duplicate node WITHIN the upper/parent element using XSLT 1.0? I use xsltproc processor.

Input.xml

```
<testng-results>
    <suite>
        <test>
            <class name="system.apps.CreateTerritory">
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="FAIL"  name="ABC"> </test-method>
            </class>
            <class name="system.apps.CreateAccount">
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="SKIP"  name="DEF"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="FAIL"  name="DEF"> </test-method>
            </class>
            <class name="system.apps.CreateProposal">
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="SKIP"  name="DEF"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="PASS"  name="initTest" is-config="true"> </test-method>
                <test-method status="FAIL"  name="DEF"> </test-method>
            </class>
        </test>
    </suite>
</testng-results>
```

My Current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="test-by-name" match="test-method[not(@is-config)]" use="@name" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Suite>
            <xsl:for-each select="testng-results/suite/test/class">
                 <xsl:for-each select="test-method[not(@is-config)][count(. | key('test-by-name', @name)[last()]) = 1]">
                             <Test>
                                 <Class_Name>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
                                 </Class_Name>
                                 <Method_Name>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                 </Method_Name>
                                 <Status>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                                 </Status>
                             </Test>
                 </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Suite>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: I can't change the way the nested match is done (for-each class and then for-each test-method as I need to be this way for other reasons)

Current Output.xml (the problem is that the duplicity is being checked ACROSS classes instead of WITHIN that class):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Suite>
  <Test>
    <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateTerritory</Class_Name>
    <Method_Name>ABC</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateProposal</Class_Name>
    <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
</Suite>
```

Expected Output.xml (only the last node is outputted for every duplicate test-method WITHIN THAT CLASS):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Suite>
<Test>
  <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateTerritory</Class_Name>
  <Method_Name>ABC</Method_Name>
  <Status>FAIL</Status>
</Test>
<Test>
  <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateAccount</Class_Name>
  <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
  <Status>FAIL</Status>
</Test>
<Test>
  <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateProposal</Class_Name>
  <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
  <Status>FAIL</Status>
</Test>
</Suite>
```

Comment: Is it coincidence that expected nodes have status *FAIL*? Why not use `last()` node position?

Comment: Just a coincidence.. The status could be anything. Fail/Pass/Skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194516/xslt-1-0-xsltproc-output-only-the-last-duplicate-node/56194660?noredirect=1#comment99213939_56194660), you need to add a class identifier to the key. Assuming that each class has a unique `name`, this could be:

```
<xsl:key name="test-by-name" match="test-method[not(@is-config)]" use="concat(@name, '|', ../@name)" />
```

Then:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="test-by-name" match="test-method[not(@is-config)]" use="concat(@name, '|', ../@name)" />

<xsl:template match="/testng-results">
    <Suite>
        <xsl:for-each select="suite/test/class/test-method[not(@is-config)][count(. | key('test-by-name', concat(@name, '|', ../@name))[last()]) = 1]">
            <Test>
                <Class_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
                </Class_Name>
                <Method_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </Method_Name>
                <Status>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                </Status>
            </Test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Suite>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Suite>
  <Test>
    <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateTerritory</Class_Name>
    <Method_Name>ABC</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateAccount</Class_Name>
    <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Class_Name>system.apps.CreateProposal</Class_Name>
    <Method_Name>DEF</Method_Name>
    <Status>FAIL</Status>
  </Test>
</Suite>
```

Comment: Perfect solution.